# Typescript type that accepts every object interface

Tags: typescript

I have multiple functions that get the same type but return a different type of interface.
I want to create a type for those functions, but when I write:

`const f: (arg: number) => Object = func;`

I get an error: `Type (arg: number) => SomeInteface is not assignable to type (arg: number) => Object`

I could just use `(arg: number) => any` but I kind of defeats the whole purpose of it being typed.
I just want it to accept all Objects and not just a specific interface because I have plenty.

For example, I'm implementing communication protocols:

```
interface splPacket {
    serviceType: number,
    serviceSubType: number,
    satelliteTime: Date,
    data: Buffer
}

function decodeSpl(input: Buffer): splPacket {...}
function encodeSpl(input: splPacket): Buffer {...}

const spl = {
    decode: decodeSpl,
    encode: encodeSpl
};

interface ax25Packet {
    destCallsign: string,
    destSSID: number,
    srcCallsign: string,
    srcSSID: number,
    data: Buffer
}

function decodeAx25(input: Buffer): ax25Packet {...}
function encodeAx25(input: ax25Packet): Buffer {...}

const ax25 = {
    decode: decodeAx25,
    encode: encodeAx25
};


interface commProtcol {
   decode: (input: Buffer): Object;
   encode: (input: Object): Buffer;
};

const protocol: commProtocol = spl;
```

But `spl` and `ax25` won't be assignable to `commProtocol`.
I want to create an interface that will allow all my communication protocols implementations.

What should I do?

Comment: Does `object` work for you? Notice lower case

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek `object` still doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] as described in [ask]?  Right now [I can't reproduce your issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECS5rxLIDeAsAFDLJwBcyAzmFKAOYVUBGdIArph9ADcFAL4UAJhAQAbOFBQJ0IRshh0AFHJbc+AqAEpkAXgB8aLLnyxEEYeUXKwybck1QXvftEOnk6DgBWUk5GqoJAA) so I can't advise.  Good luck!

Comment: Which version of typescript do you use?

Comment: @jcalz I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

So, I can't reproduce the error as you've written it.  If I have types `X`, `T`, and `U`, where `U extends T`, then a function of the form `(a: X)=>U` should be assignable to a variable annotated as `(a: X)=>T`, and not vice versa.  Another way of saying this is that functions should be [covariant in their output types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types).  In particular, `(a: number)=>SomeInterface` should be assignable to a variable annotated as `(a: number)=>object`.  And it is; I don't see an error of that sort in your code.

When I put your example code into an IDE, the error I see is this:

```
const protocol: CommProtocol = spl;
/* Types of property 'encode' are incompatible.
   Type '(input: SplPacket) => Buffer' is not assignable to type '(input: object) => Buffer'.
*/
```

This is complaining about the *argument* to the function, not to the *return type*.  If I have types `X`, `T`, and `U`, where `U extends T`, then a function of the form `(a: T)=>X` should be assignable to a variable annotated as `(a: U)=>X` and not vice versa.  Another way of saying this is that functions should be contravariant in their input types.  In particular, `(a: object)=>Buffer` should *not* be assignable to a variable annotated as `(a: SplPacket)=>Buffer`.  And it isn't.  That's why you're getting the error.

It's unsound to try to treat `spl.encode` as if it were a valid `encode` property of `CommProtocol`.  After all, I expect `protocol.encode()` to accept *any object whatsoever* as its input.  So `protocol.encode({foo: "", bar: 1})` should be fine.  But `spl.encode()` expects an `SplPacket`, not a `{foo: string, bar: number}`.  It's likely to blow up at runtime.

---

So what can we do here?  Assuming you actually want type safety, the solution is probably to make `CommProtocol` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the type of object you're talking about.  Like this:

```
interface CommProtocol<T extends object> {
    decode: (input: Buffer) => T;
    encode: (input: T) => Buffer;
}
```

`CommProtocol` is no longer a complete interface name by itself... it needs a type parameter to make it complete.  A `CommProtocol<T>` can encode a `T` into a `Buffer` and decode a `Buffer` into a `T`.   A `CommProtocol<object>` is equivalent to your old definition of `CommProtocol` (and therefore inappropriate for `spl`).  And a `CommProtocol<SplPacket>` can encode a `SplPacket` into a `Buffer` and decode a `Buffer` into a `SplPacket`, so the following compiles with no error:

```
const goodProtocol: CommProtocol<SplPacket> = spl; // okay
```

If you don't want to have to hand-annotate each `CommProtocol` type parameter, you can have a helper function that lets the compiler infer the particular type parameter for each value:

```
const asProtocol = <T extends object>(t: CommProtocol<T>) => t;
```

And here's how you'd use it:

```
const alsoGoodProtocol = asProtocol(spl); // CommProtocol<SplPacket>
const anotherProtocol = asProtocol(ax25); // CommProtocol<Ax25Packet>
```

Okay, looks good.  Hope that gives you some direction; good luck!

[Playground Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAIQK4DMUFMpxVCI4DkAdhACboECwAUDcETJigIYDG6cAymADYAKbANbp4AbxpxJcAM6YAbsHYAVAJ5h0ALjhEkIAEaYANBKmyoC9pyR7V6rTv1GTk6c0Y8ewRktCa4AETd0Y2opOFI3Zi1kNEwaAF8aclYeZigOFCQiVhhgCCJw9FYydG4eAAp6MCQYaNQMKABKLTKBVmEYAG4kotT07CycvIL0bJKyyqJq2q5eNo7mxHrMbupioml4aV44AF44cVCpZJKtE-IykLDR4vItG-HeBNW6BiY2DgBBAA8AJgBWeYiA7OQqbADCzA80mAAHMiFpNlB6LCrsd0JtOJwAJL+ey6AxQNEuKCsSHQuEImQwZFEVGg6SkrG4-GOImgiIwKJLWJQBI0HopNIZQa5fKFW7oH4AybTOq8xbSwFCESrZJ9EXZMUjMbkJWympaJVAmCLGINVbrTZwZh-f57EFHSTnPwupXEuAPO6e3VSu3POAC6j0RhQFjsRDMUjgvAgPi4GAQYo8R1hF1aA0zc2YRp7AB8cAgegAVkUuqCvX5M1oi6WcrndgXs1BVvFLflrWAE0mIDxolGYyA493kw7tjxVgB6ABUcFsGMLKDgXYg6lgKkIlYINv69GK4DcwD0PHQADpnPPCNXZvwVab8zyGtvgNJtBB4MxpDD4cxjxxE3AMBqBwBDXrWZYNk2yxQAQ57UNOk5BiG7wRoOw7vj2PAADxKJ63yMEQpCvuBOQFocaZFKccDXs2kFzqs1y+hmVSGnOdHNq2NBWvAsIQGQ8YYcmWhoQJibJlhrR3gW+zjp0cCTpOhaCMwKhBtxNrSKJmEOjheEEURhYlmWeblDMIkjr2OF5nR5a0GsHYfjw0gQAA4nxpBaaO+yfp5vblOOjRyQpcDmYJlmSe0Ih5lxDk2iQMAABaYL5KbeZpFkVLaAKBfJimhWJlnGlJNBAA)